# How to slideIn hidden component in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've got the following situation: some controls that are located next to a button and are slided in and out on button click.

```
Ext.define ('Site.widget.SomeButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    xtype: 'SomeButton',
    width: 30,
    controlled_inputs: null,
    expanded: false,
    setControlledCmp: function(controlledInputs) {
        var me = this;
        me.on('click', function(){
            if (me.expanded)
                controlledInputs.getEl().slideOut('r', { duration: 250 });
            else
                controlledInputs.getEl().slideIn('r', { duration: 250 });
            me.expanded = !me.expanded;
        }); 
    }
});

Ext.define('Site.widget.ComingOut', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'ComingOut',
    layout: 'hbox',
    header: false,    
    referenceHolder: true,    
    items:[{
        xtype: 'SomeItems',
        reference: 'SomeItems'
    },{
        xtype: 'SomeButton',
        reference: 'SomeButton'
    }],

    onBoxReady: function() {
        me.lookupReference('SomeButton').setControlledItems(me.lookupReference('SomeItems'));
    }
});
```

The code works fine when the controls are initially shown. The question is: what should I do if I want them to be initially hidden? `hidden:false` is not the option since when controls are hidden the button moves into the freed position. I suppose I am missing something easy here. Thank you in advance!

---

PS I've found solution, though it doesn't seem good enough (hides element instead of correctly setting its initial state), so if anyone knows a better one - you are welcome. My solution is the following

```
setControlledCmp: function(controlled_inputs) {
    var me = this;
    me.on('click', function( view, eOpts ){
        controlled_inputs.setOpacity(1);
        if (me.expanded)
            controlled_inputs.slideOut('r', { duration: 250 });
        else
            controlled_inputs.slideIn('r', { duration: 250 });
        me.expanded = !me.expanded;
    }); 
}
```

and

```
onBoxReady: function() {
    var me = this;
    var inputs = me.lookupReference('search_inputs').getEl();
    inputs.setOpacity(0);
    inputs.slideOut('r', { duration: 5 });
    me.lookupReference('search_button').setControlledCmp(inputs);
}
```